# ViewController以外はデリゲート先になれない？

Tags: swift, delegate

初歩的なことが理解できていないのだと思います。

```
class MyView : UIView,UITextViewDelegate{  
    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:100,height:100))

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      textView.delegate = self
      addSubview(textView)
    }
 }
```

としたら、MyView内でUITextViewDelegateの処理(例えばtextViewDidChange)を記述できないかと思うのですが、実際は書いても動きません。ViewControllerでのデリゲートの動作は確認済みですが、ViewController以外のクラスでは不可能なのでしょうか。よくあるhoge〜などで説明してあるデリゲートの概念ではできそうに思うのですが。不可能ならば、その理由もご教示いただければ助かります。

Comment: DelegateにはViewControllerに限らず任意のオブジェクトを設定できます。UIKit由来のものはクラスのインスタンスという制限がついていることが多いですが、UIViewをデリゲートに設定することは問題ありません。メソッドが呼ばれないのは別の何か間違いをしているはずです。

Comment: すみません、問題の切り分けが不十分でした。無事設定できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 正しくは、textViewDidChangeなどの既存のものは呼び出せるが、extension UITextViewDelegate{}内に宣言したメソッドが呼び出せない、でした。こちらも何かしら勘違いをしているのだと思います。なんにせよ表題の問題は解決いたしましたのでお礼申し上げます。